# How to get annotation with default value in scala

Tags: scala

all:

How to get annotation object with default value of comment?

```
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation
import scala.reflect.runtime._
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._

// The annotation has default value
case class Table(idField: String = "") extends StaticAnnotation

@Table()
case class SomeEntity()


println(getClassAnnotation[Table](classOf[SomeEntity]).idField)

def getClassAnnotation[A: TypeTag](beanClazz: Class[_]): A = {
  val typeAnnotation=currentMirror.typeOf[A]
  currentMirror.classSymbol(beanClazz).toType.typeSymbol.asClass.annotations.find(a => a.tree.tpe == typeAnnotation).map {
    annotation =>
      val value = annotation.tree.children.tail.map(_.productElement(0).asInstanceOf[Constant].value)
      currentMirror.reflectClass(typeAnnotation.typeSymbol.asClass).
        reflectConstructor(typeAnnotation.decl(termNames.CONSTRUCTOR).asMethod)(value: _*)
  }.get.asInstanceOf[A]
}
```

The error is

```
java.lang.ClassCastException: scala.reflect.internal.Trees$Select cannot be cast to scala.reflect.api.Constants$ConstantApi
```

If override value will pass , like this

```
@Table(idField="code")
case class SomeEntity()
```

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to use `scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox` to achieve this:

```
import scala.tools.reflect.ToolBox
val tb = currentMirror.mkToolBox()
val result = tb.eval(tb.untypecheck(annotation.tree)).asInstanceOf[Table]
```

This will produce the result as the case class `Table` with all the fields, including defaults.